# Will JIRA clash with Plesk on Install

Tags: server, installation, jira, plesk, ports

I have a dedicated hosting account that is managed using Plesk (i am not very comfortable with Linux command line - learning). Plesk is fine as its easy to use for managing different web spaces.

1. I want to know if i install JIRA on the same server will i run into
   any issues with Plesk.  I believe the ports used for Plesk and JIRA
   are not the same (8080 for JIRA).
2. Are there any good walk throughs for doing so
3. Any recommendations on the install process
4. Eventually, i want JIRA to be accessed via subdomain url j.domain.com and not xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx. how could i set this up

thanks a lot!

Comment: What OS you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JIRA can be installed on Plesk server without any issues.

1. There is port clash only with Tomcat, so if you have it installed JIRA installer suggest you to choose another port.
2. ```
   # wget https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/downloads/binary/atlassian-jira-software-7.2.4-x64.bin
   # chmod +x atlassian-jira-software-7.2.4-x64.bin
   # ./atlassian-jira-software-7.2.4-x64.bin
   ```
3. - It's better to use MySQL database if you haven't experience with PostgreSQL.
   - JIRA installer always ***silently*** fallback to built in H2 file database in case of issue with provided DB settings
   - you have to create domain, database and mail user in plesk
4. You have to enable `proxy_http` in `Tools&Settings` > `Apache Web Server` and create file `/httpdocs/.htaccess` in `j.domain.com` domain to redirect requests to JIRA:

   ```
   RewriteEngine  on
   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
   ```

SMTP settings:
[image: JIRA SMTP server settings]

Troubleshooting:

- Logs are placed here /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out

Comment: thanks. I noticed that when using you method jiva has a difficult time locating all the images and such. ( my sidebar is empy and my icons too) if i switch the url from the domain to the specific port this is gone. Im curious if there is a way to fix this.

Comment: @user1712804 try to replace in .htaccess file host 127.0.0.1 with j.domain.com but pay attention that j.domain.com should be resolving from server or you get 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Instead of using .htaccess you can use the "Additional Apache directives" in Plesk for your domain (under "Apache & nginx Settings") and configure the proxying. See here for details: [link](https://www.conetix.com.au/support/article/plesk-12-running-mod_proxy-to-use-nodejs).
Though you still have to enable "proxy_http" in Plesk of course.